# Performant fixed array range that changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, range, scale

This question is a little difficult to ask because I'm not quite sure what I'm asking. I know how it "should" work in my head.

**The problem:**

I'm trying to create an index that uses an array of a fixed size, to implement a "range"-like lookup.

**Example:**

Given an array length of `10`, and we push:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Everything works out! It fits properly.

However, given an array length of `12`, and we push `24` items into it;

we should receive something like:

`[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24]`

Let's check whether to add the number `13` into it.

`[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24]`

Okay, nothing to be done here. `13` falls between a valid range.. so we don't add it.

Now let's add the number `28` into it.

`[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 28]`

But now we have `25` items in it. I'm not sure what should happen here, but I'd imagine we want to re-arrange the array. We ideally want to `cap` the array to a fixed size, but need a way to create a new set of ranges.

This should also work on the inverse, if we have an array of:

`[4, 7, 10]` - max size of `3`

and we add `1` to it, we need to create a new range.

`[1, 3, 10]`

I hope I've made this question clear.. I'm actually not sure if this is even the best way to accomplish my goals. All I know is that I want a fixed array size, and to be able to index the 'items' into it so I can use it as a range.

The primary reason I'm concerned about performance is because this should be able to handle arrays of several hundred items (or even thousands).

Similar questions here: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099244/split-javascript-array-of-numbers-into-ranges), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025608/interpolate-between-dates-given-known-index-range)

Comment: `arrays of several hundred items (or even thousands).` is *absolutely nothing* to any modern computer, best not to worry about optimization until you *know* you need to speed something up

Comment: I'm mostly concerned about re-indexing performance hits. If we add items to the end, that will mean that we have to re-create the range - unless there's another way to do it..

Comment: is it not possible to put a loop that - since you know the initial range array - populates an empty array by following the range and only insert (or adjust) when required?

Comment: "since you know the initial range array", I don't know the initial array data. It will be populated on demand. (Through events, user interaction, etc). I'm opened to examples, but thinking theory isn't my strong suit.

Comment: If you were to "compress" the data elements one at a time, you wouldn't end up with the same data than if you tried to compress the final array into a smaller one.  If the point of this was to reduce space in memory, than as you described it, it is not possible.

Comment: I highly dislike "it is not possible". Over the years, I've proven several cases where people told me it isn't possible. Just gotta think outside the box. I'm not concerned about "same data", as the index is a range. That would be serializable to a Number in some form.

Comment: @LeviRoberts What if I told you to find the median of a set of data, except I gave you only 10% of the total set?  You may be close, but you cannot say you absolutely positively have the median representing the entire set.  It isn't impossible in an absolute sense, but rather only in the case in which you don't have the entire array to start with.